# How to run tabactivity in a fragment?

Tags: android

```
public class Test extends Fragment {


    EditText subject,bodybd;
    TextView buttonpass;
    private long mLastClickTime = 0;
    TabHost tHost;

    public static Test newInstance() {
        Test fragment = new Test();
        return fragment;
    }


    ImageView my_loc_btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTitleFragment("Email to GSD");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.store_location, container, false);

        my_loc_btn=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_loc_btn);

        my_loc_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Fragment newFragment = new MyLocation();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.tabcontent, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

//        ///// set tab content////



        Resources ressources = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
         tabHost.setup();
        // List tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(),NewMapShow.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Android")
                .setIndicator("Android",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nicon))
                .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // map tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), MyLocation.class);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Apple")
                .setIndicator("Apple",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nicon))
                .setContent(intentApple);


        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);


        /** Defining Tab Change Listener event. This is invoked when tab is changed */
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {


            }
        };

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);









        /////////end of tabfragment//////////////






        return rootView;
    }















    protected void setTitleFragment(String strTitle){
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView txtTitle =((TextView)mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title));
        txtTitle.setText(strTitle);
    }


}
```

and my logcat message:

```
                     Process: com.nahid.com.gsdambassadorpractice, PID: 22380
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'
                                                                                     at android.widget.TabHost.setup(TabHost.java:132)
                                                                                     at com.nahid.com.gsdambassadorpractice.fragment.Test.onCreateView(Test.java:85)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
```

now i want to know how can i run tabactivity in a fragment.Also how to change fragment on tab click.Above code is crushing the application.Please help me how can i solve this problem.

Comment: add  <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" in your xml

Comment: by default it is given.give me another solution